# Update ListView without data beiing changed

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

In my app I have a `ListView` that contains times of different timezones. With a `seekbar`the user can change the current time of a timezone and the other zones are supposed to update their times as well.

In my `onCreate()` method I iniciate the `ListView` and set a Time variable to the current time of my previously selected location. In addition I set a`OnSeekBarChangeListener` to my `seekbar`.

```
private ArrayList<Welt> welts;
private SimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    arrayAdapter = new SimpleArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listwelt, welts);
    showwelt();

    ...

    now.setToNow();
    now.set(now.toMillis(false));
    pos = extras.getInt("weltcompare");
    now.switchTimezone(welts.get(pos).zone);

    ...

    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            offset = seekBar.getProgress()*5 - start;
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //showwelt();
        }

        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            offset = seekBar.getProgress()*5 - start;
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            //showwelt();
        }

    });

    ...

}

public void showwelt() {
    ListView listTest = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistwelt);
    listTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listTest.setDivider(null);
    listTest.setDividerHeight(0);
}
```

At last my ArrayAdapter class:

```
public class SimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Welt> {
    private final int resource;

    public SimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Welt> arrays) {
        super(context, resource, arrays);
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Welt cobject = getItem(position);
        RelativeLayout listView;

        if(convertView==null) {
            listView = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
            String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
            vi.inflate(resource, listView, true);
        }else{
            listView = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        }

        TextView tv1 = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.listwelt1);
        tv1.setText(cobject.ort);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.listwelt2);
        tv2.setText(cobject.land);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.listwelt3);
        now.set(base);
        now.minute = now.minute + offset;
        now.normalize(false);
        now.set(now.toMillis(false));
        now.switchTimezone(cobject.zone);
        tv3.setText(TimeMateActivity.formatDateTime(0, 0, 0, now.hour, now.minute));
        TextView tv4 = (TextView)listView.findViewById(R.id.listwelt4);
        tv4.setText(TimeMateActivity.formatDateTime(now.monthDay, now.month, now.year, 24, 0));

        if(position == pos) {
            tv1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            tv3.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        return listView;
    }
}
```

So the only data that is changed while the activity is running is the variable offset.
I think that's the reason why `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work, while calling showwelt() in the `OnSeekBarChangeListener` does the job, but resets the `ListView` to the top.

I read a couple of posts, but none of them helped.
I tried to clear the adapter and add all items again before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
I tried saving the current scroll position of the list and restore it.

How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

My `OnSeekBarChangeListener` methods now look like this.

`OnProgressChanged`: here I calculate the value for my offset variable and call the `showwelt()` function

`OnStartTrackingTouch`: here I save the current scroll position of the listview

`OnStopTrackingTouch`: empty

And my `showwelt` function looks like this:

```
public void showwelt() {
    ListView listTest = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mylistwelt);
    SimpleArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listwelt, welts);
    listTest.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listTest.setDivider(null);
    listTest.setDividerHeight(0);
    listTest.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are using "now" in your adapter, so you're never to to be able to change it.  You need to find a way to get the seekbar value into the adapter and use that instead of "now".  then use `.invalidate()` to force a redraw of the list .

Comment: I tried that, too. But not with .invalidate(). Just did a quick test again. I created a new variable for the object I put in may ArrayList and then in my adapter. In this variable I save the value offset, which is calculated when the seekbar is moved. Then I calld listview.invalidate() instead of arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). But still, the listview isn't updatet at all.